# How to loop through the rows of a continuous form in microsoft access and insert value into unbound textbox using vba?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a continuous form of an access database table which is editable. I added a column to the form (not the access database table) and inserted an unbound textbox in this column with no value.
When the form is loaded it runs a VBA that queries an online database, does some calculations and would like to insert those calculations into this unbound textbox in respect to that rows value.

[image]

I want the unbound textbox to show value respective to that row only, but instead the entire column of unbound text is assigned the same value.

I do not want to join tables as it makes the form not editable. I have also done dlookup, it works, but it makes the form extremely slow.

I have also tried using spacesaver columns like

```
select '' as column1, '' as column2 from table;
```

and used the vba records set to edit those values, but those space saver columns are not editable as its an expression. When i did

```
rs.Edit
rs.fields("column1") = "something"
rs.Update
```

the vba breaks when i do this as the the column i am trying to edit is an expression and is not editable.

Comment: Either save the calculated value to a field in table or call a function with an argument for field2 data from the unbound textbox. You successfully used DLookup and VBA might not be any faster. Code should be posted as formatted text, not image. Also preferable to provide data as a text table instead of image.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use an unbound textbox to do that. On a continuous form your unbound textbox will have the same value on each line. Internaly there is only one textbox that is printed on each line. There is not one textbox per line.

Try simply

```vb
Me.MyUnboundTextboxName = "SomeValue"
```

You'll see `SomeValue` appear on every line.