# Make a Subform Combo Box to show results based upon data in its row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, subform

MS Access: 2016

I have a subform with two combo boxes.  There is a unique ID field on each row (this comes from the form’s SQL).  I want to use that ID value in the SQL that populates the Combo Box.  However, the combo boxes show results only for the ID from the first row.  Is there a way to have access use the ID value from each row?

The first Combo Box on each row has two columns to demonstrate the issue.  Here we see the last row combo box using the ID from the first row.  I want each combo box to use the ID from its row.
[image]

Restating the issue using ID numbers:  In the above example the last row combo box displays the results for ID = 138908.  It should display the results from ID = 138917.  Actually all rows use the ID from the first row (ID = 138908).

Any thoughts on how to pull the ID from the row the combo box is on?

Here is the SQL from the first combo box:

```
SELECT 
  codes_bis_vio.violation, 
  codes_bis_vio_choice.bis_log_id 
FROM 
  codes_bis_vio 
  INNER JOIN codes_bis_vio_choice ON codes_bis_vio.bis_vio_code = codes_bis_vio_choice.bis_vio_code 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      (
        codes_bis_vio_choice.bis_log_id
      )= [Forms] ! [frmDailyPoints] ! [frmDailyPointsPrevBisSub].[Form] ! [ID]
    )
  );
```

And the table relationship

[image]

And the subform in design mode:

[image]

Comment: This is called cascading combobox, a common topic. Need code in form Current event as well as ID AfterUpdate to requery the combobox.

Comment: Why are you not linking on PK ID in codes_bis_vio? If you are saving bis_vio_code text value then this should be the designated primary key and then the ID is irrelevent. What table is form bound to? Combobox RowSource SQL should not need a JOIN of tables.

Comment: @braX There isn't much in the way of code at this point.  Just the forms, tables and SQL. I'm porting the application from an Access backend to MS SQL.  Originally the combo boxes where multi-value fields (MVF's). I removed the MVF's and want to port/show all the values in a combo box.

Comment: @June7 To your first post:  Hmm, I think you are right. This is probably a good use case for cascading Combo boxes.  I've not implemented them before but I understand the concept.  I'll check them out.  I assume the AfterUpdate event be on the subform?

Comment: I can't follow the logic behind the table structure and query, but if the rows behavior variable is based on the row's severity id then just set the behavior textbox's control source to a dlookup function.  something like DLOOKUP("Behavior", "SomeTableWithBehaviors",  "[Severity ID] = " & [Severity ID] )

Comment: As I said, form Current event and ID AfterUpdate. And after looking at this some more, I am with @mazoula, not understanding relationship. DLookup() might not be best option for pulling associated value. Can perform slowly.

Comment: Alternatives are: 1) include lookup table in form RecordSource and bind textbox to associated fields set as Locked Yes and TabStop No; 2) included associated fields in combobox RowSource and textbox expression references column by index - if data is in column 4 its index is 3 `=cboSeverity.Column(3)`. So maybe you don't want a cascading combobox.

Comment: Well, according to this answer I cannot do what want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275559/run-vba-for-each-record-in-a-form
I’ll try the suggestion and iterate though each record after the form is drawn and set the me.cbo.RowSource to a SQL using the ID.value for that row. Then requery it.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot update unbounded control on each row of a continuous form.
[How to loop through the rows of a continuous form in microsoft access and insert value into unbound textbox using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839788/how-to-loop-through-the-rows-of-a-continuous-form-in-microsoft-access-and-insert)

Time to explore other options.  Appreciate all the suggested answers!